# Cannot get user object right way after creating it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I'm using userDetailsManager to create new user and right way trying to get MyUser object from database. Here is an example:

```
User user = new User(username, passwordHash, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
userDetailsManager.createUser(user);

MyUser current = users.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
```

---

```
public MyUser findByUsername(String username) {
    TypedQuery<MyUser> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select u from User u where u.username = :username", User.class);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    return query.getResultList().get(0);
}
```

And it always returns null.

Checking DB - everything is in place.
Why?

Comment: Is your `userDetailsManager` an extension of `EntityManager`? If so, try calling `userDetailsManager.flush();` after you create your user.

Comment: No, `userDetailsManager` from `org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager`

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`EntityManager#flush`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Flush) right after you are executing the insert. The record might be flushed in the DB but the EMs cache wasn't probably refreshed yet so that's why you receive this result.

You should also use `getSingleResult` instead of `getResultList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your autocommit will be false and you are inserting data that will remains in session object try by commiting transaction after insertion

Comment: Can you give an example, please?